# Sum of elements based on unique names across a list(unknown length) of data frames

Tags: r

I am trying to get the `sum` of elements based on unique names across a `list` containing unknown number of `dataframes`.

```
## Test Data
Name1 <- c("A","B","C","D")
Name2 <- c("A","D")
Name3 <- c("B","C","F")
Values1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
Values2 <- c(5,7)
Values3 <- c(6,8,9)
DF1 <- data.frame(Name1,Values1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DF2 <- data.frame(Name2,Values2,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DF3 <- data.frame(Name3,Values3,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DFList <- list(DF1,DF2,DF3)
```

My Output will be:

```
A  B  C  D  F 
6  8 11 11  9
```

I am not sure if using a loop is effective, since there can be any number of dataframes in the list and the number of unique rows in a dataframe can range anywhere between 100,000 to 1 Million.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution using `data.table::rbindlist`:

```
data.table::rbindlist(DFList)[, sum(Values1), Name1]
```

> ```
>    Name1 V1
> 1:     A  6
> 2:     B  8
> 3:     C 11
> 4:     D 11
> 5:     F  9
> ```

`rbindlist` binds columns despite their names and then you can `sum(Values1)` by `Name1`.

Comment: now you are faster ;-)

Comment: Sweet  and short. Thanks!!

Comment: you could also use `use.names = FALSE` like: `data.table::rbindlist(DFList, use.names = FALSE)[, sum(Values), by = Name]`

Comment: Awesome solution

Answer (score 3):

```
sapply(split(unlist(lapply(DFList, "[[", 2)), unlist(lapply(DFList, "[[", 1))), sum)
# A  B  C  D  F 
# 6  8 11 11  9
```

OR

```
aggregate(formula = Value~Name,
          data = do.call(rbind, lapply(DFList, function(x) setNames(x, c("Name", "Value")))),
          FUN = sum)
#  Name Value
#1    A     6
#2    B     8
#3    C    11
#4    D    11
#5    F     9
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the answer of @d.b.

```
lst <- unlist(lapply(DFList, function(DF) setNames(DF[[2]], DF[[1]])))
tapply(lst, names(lst), sum)
#A  B  C  D  F 
#6  8 11 11  9
```